# How to get a token bluecheck from polygonscan?

Tags: erc-20, etherscan

I would like to ask about blue checks in polygon scans.
Is there any documentation that we need to submit to receive a blue check for our token registered with polygonscan?

On the polygonscan supporter homepage([https://support.polygonscan.com/support/solutions/articles/69000793859-the-blue-checkmark-✔](https://support.polygonscan.com/support/solutions/articles/69000793859-the-blue-checkmark-%E2%9C%94)), there are only evaluation criteria, but there is no information about what materials we need to submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no method to get blue check on Polygon scan. If you’re token pass all the criteria required for your token then it might receive a bluecheck from polygon scan itself.

**Requirements mentioned in docs:**

- The contract source code must be verified
- The token project must represent a known & public interest project.
- The token project must maintain a working website with active social
  profiles and communication channels.
- The token project has operated for a period of time and achieved
  certain milestones
- The token projects remains active and has ongoing on-chain activities
- The token project is well known and often interacted.